# How to get user-roles with sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, sequelize.js

I have a realtion like this:

[image]

in my resolver I am fetching the enteties like this:

```
users: async () => {
  const users = await db.user.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: db.userroles,
        include: [
          {
            model: db.roles,
            attributes: ['Name'],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  });
```

I log what I get from the db:

```
 console.log('users are', users[0].dataValues.userroles[0].dataValues.role.Name); // logs "users are developer"
```

Which shows me that the correct roles are fetched.

My graphql schema:

```
  type user {
    Id: ID!
    Email: String
    RoleId: Int!
    Password: String
    ChangedPassword: Boolean
    WeddingId: Int!
    AttendantId: Int
    role: [roles!]
  }

  type roles {
    Id: ID!
    Name: String!
  }
```

In the playground I am sending this:

```
{users
  {role
  {Name}}
}
```

result:

```
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "role": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I log the entire user object that I get back from the db:

```
users are userroles {
  dataValues:
   { UserId: 1,
     RoleId: 1,
     role:
      roles {
        dataValues: [Object],
        _previousDataValues: [Object],
        _changed: {},
        _modelOptions: [Object],
        _options: [Object],
        isNewRecord: false } },
  _previousDataValues:
   { UserId: 1,
     RoleId: 1,
     role:
      roles {
        dataValues: [Object],
        _previousDataValues: [Object],
        _changed: {},
        _modelOptions: [Object],
        _options: [Object],
        isNewRecord: false } },
  _changed: {},
  _modelOptions:
   { timestamps: false,
     validate: {},
     freezeTableName: true,
     underscored: false,
     paranoid: false,
     rejectOnEmpty: false,
     whereCollection: null,
     schema: null,
     schemaDelimiter: '',
     defaultScope: {},
     scopes: {},
     indexes: [],
     name: { plural: 'userroles', singular: 'userrole' },
     omitNull: false,
     tableName: 'userroles',
     sequelize:
      Sequelize {
        options: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        dialect: [MysqlDialect],
        queryInterface: [QueryInterface],
        models: [Object],
        modelManager: [ModelManager],
        connectionManager: [ConnectionManager],
        importCache: [Object] },
     hooks: {} },
  _options:
   { isNewRecord: false,
     _schema: null,
     _schemaDelimiter: '',
     include: [ [Object] ],
     includeNames: [ 'role' ],
     includeMap: { role: [Object] },
     includeValidated: true,
     raw: true,
     attributes: undefined },
  isNewRecord: false,
  role:
   roles {
     dataValues: { Name: 'Developer' },
     _previousDataValues: { Name: 'Developer' },
     _changed: {},
     _modelOptions:
      { timestamps: false,
        validate: {},
        freezeTableName: true,
        underscored: false,
        paranoid: false,
        rejectOnEmpty: false,
        whereCollection: null,
        schema: null,
        schemaDelimiter: '',
        defaultScope: {},
        scopes: {},
        indexes: [],
        name: [Object],
        omitNull: false,
        tableName: 'roles',
        sequelize: [Sequelize],
        hooks: {} },
     _options:
      { isNewRecord: false,
        _schema: null,
        _schemaDelimiter: '',
        include: undefined,
        includeNames: undefined,
        includeMap: undefined,
        includeValidated: true,
        raw: true,
        attributes: [Array] },
     isNewRecord: false } }
```

I am getting the roles I just can't figure out how to present them?

I think that the issue is in my resolver that I am missing yet another set of includes but I cant figure out how to write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user` and `roles` have a many-to-many relationship with `userRoles` as the junction table. If you have not already, should should define this relationship on `user`:

```
user.belongsToMany(roles, { through: userRoles })
```

This will let you `include` roles directly:

```
const users = await db.user.findAll({
  include: [
    db.roles,
  ],
});
```

Comment: Did not know this, Thanks!

Comment: Just thought of something, might be irrelevant since the above works but just out of curiosity. Should it not be roles.belongsToMany(user, { through: userRoles }) ?

Comment: Relationships are always one-directional. With many-to-many, you typically do *both*. `user.belongsToMany(roles)` lets you access a user's roles via `user.roles`. `roles.belongsToMany(user)` lets you access all the users for a role via `role.users`. If you don't need one or the other, you can omit declaring that relationship.

Answer (score 1):

After posting I noticed some issues in my schema.

I changed my schema to:

```
  type roles {
    Id: ID!
    Name: String!
  }

  type userroles {
    RoleId: ID!
    UserId: ID!
    role: roles
  }

  type user {
    Id: ID!
    Email: String
    RoleId: Int!
    Password: String
    ChangedPassword: Boolean
    WeddingId: Int!
    AttendantId: Int
    userroles: [userroles!]
  }
```

playground:

```
{users
  {userroles
  {role
  {Name}}}
}
```

result:

```
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "userroles": [
          {
            "role": {
              "Name": "Developer"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The answer stared me right in the face but I was focused on the code in the resolver.

Leaving this question in case someone has another way of doing this.

Comment: change names ... types uppercased, properies/fields lowercased ... `type User { id: ID!, changedPassword ...`

Comment: The thing is im using  sequelize-auto and it generates all table names with lovercase.

Comment: it's not sequelize-auto fault - existing db names (rename db tables?) ... at least you can use `-C, --camel       Use camel case to name models and fields`